# Why two requests are displayed in Fiddler2 when first request sent to BlazeDS using RemoteObject of Flex

Tags: apache-flex, spring, blazeds, fiddler, remoteobject

Why are two requests displayed in Fiddler2 when first request sent to BlazeDS using RemoteObject of Flex.

I use this enviroment:

- Flex SDK 3.5
- BlazeDS 4.0.1
- Spring 3.0.5
- Spring BlazeDS Integration 1.0.3

Comment: Wow, most appropriate name for someone that doesn't accept *any* answers. You should give back :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the first request an OPTIONS or HEAD request?